# Drupal Feeds showing encoded HTML markup

Tags: drupal

Can't figure out why this is happening, but my RSS feeds are showing HTML encoding in the description field that I need to get rid of:

For example:

```
<description>&lt;div class=&quot;field field-type-text field-field-location&quot;&gt;
```

I just can't figure out why this would be happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct. The content of `<description>` is [supposed to be](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/encodingDescriptions.html) XML-text-encoded HTML. At least for RSS 2.0; other versions of RSS are notoriously inconsistent and woolly on this matter.

(If it weren't encoded, then only well-formed and namespaced XHTML could go in the element. This approach was not taken, primarily because RSS predates XHTML.)

Comment: Ah, ok.  Thanks for the answer.  The only problem is, and this is by which I found this "issue" is that google is ranking the keyword 'div' really highly when I look in Google Webmasters.  So from an SEO perspective this is a problem.

Comment: Really? If Google's getting that from RSS 2.0 it's a bug! There is an argument for stripping all HTML markup from `<description>`, though, since there are old and horrid readers that don't treat it as encoded.

Comment: I think you are right, i'm going to investigate what is going on, rather than just trying to fix what I thought was a problem.  Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are suffering from this issue:

http://drupal.org/node/666930

It's a core PHP bug that exists in certain versions of PHP, here's the core bug:

http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45996